# Running find query for all values in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Let's say I have an array of student ids and I want to check if they are all valid inside my db. An also know which of them aren't in the db and then put them in an array called faulty.

```js
let studentIDS = [435,345,343,654];
let faulty = [];

studentIDS.forEach(i=>{
  StudentSchema.findOne(i).then(res=>{
    if(!res) faulty.push(i);
  })
})
```

This approach comes with an error because the find query is asynchronous and the forEach loop reached the end before the queries are run. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run your database query in a loop. In this case you can use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator to get the ids of matching database documents and then run simple `.filter()` to find the missing ones:

```
let studentIDS = [435,345,343,654];

let result = await StudentSchema.findOne({ _id: { $in: studentIDS } }, { _id:1 });
let resultIds = result.map(x => x._id);

let missing = studentIDS.filter(id => resultIds.indexOf(id) === -1);
```